# Seleniun does not work with a website element

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to automatic a website ckick button using selenium and the next method:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/a/div[2]/input'))).send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

The XPATH is referenced to the next website element:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY2Rl.jpg)

After inspecting the website programming, the “Subit Archivos” element is programmed like this:

```
<input accept="video/*, image/*" multiple="" display="inline-block" type="file" class="_n _5f0v" id="js_31">
```

When I executed the previous Python method, the linker gives me the next error:

“selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:”

It is like the method is no table to detect the button…Any idea why is happening this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use the ID to target the element.... also sending keys to an input tag of file type sets the 'value' of the tag (path to the file).  (which is very convenient since the browse dialog will be outside the DOM and not accesible to the webdriver...)  If you need to open the browse dialog, use click().